# iPhone OS 3.2 File Sharing Path

Tags: iphone, filesystems, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

Currently I have this for my file path and file...

```
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Shared\PartyPlanner.sqlite"]];
```

This allows me to share the file with iTunes, but instead of just having 'PartyPlanner.sqlite' in the 'applicationDocumentsDirectory\Shared'

I have "SharedPartyPlanner.sqlite" in the 'applicationDocumentsDirectory'

is there a cleaner or easier way to get to the shared folder inside of applicationDocumentsDirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UNIX-like systems (including the iPhone OS), the directory separator is `/`, not `\`.

Also, in C-like languages (including Objective-C), the `\` in a string is used to escape a character, e.g. `\n` → a new line. You need to type `Shared\\PartyPlanner.sqlite` if you really need a backslash in the file name.